# Powershell delete folder files based on date range criteria

Tags: powershell

Below command, delete files older than 30 days

```
Get-ChildItem –Path "C:\path\to\folder" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item
```

But how to add filters, that dont delete files if

```
date is 1st of each month or
date is 15th of each month or
date is 30
also ignore files with name '%weekly%'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only want to remove **files**, you should use the `-File` switch on the `Get-ChildItem`.
In order not to keep calculating the reference date 30 days ago, I like to define that in a variable `$refDate` first.
Also, you should use the date, as of midnight by setting the time part to `00:00:00`. That is where property `Date` comes in.

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date  # set it to midnight
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path\to\folder" -File -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate) -and
                   ($_.BaseName -notlike '*%weekly%*') -and
                   (1,15,30 -notcontains $_.LastWriteTime.Day)} | 
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

<sup>P.S. I have added the `-WhatIf` switch, so you can see what *would* happen first. If you are satisfied with the messages in the console, remove this switch to actually start deleting files</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can go for powershell script like below:

```bsh
$FolderName = "c:\dev\test"
foreach($file in (GEt-childitem -Path $FolderName -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} ))
{
 if (($file.lastwritetime.Date.Day  -in 1,15,30 ) -or ($file -like '*weekly*'))
 {
   continue
 }
 
 Remove-Item -Path $file.FullName
}
```