# Powershell Get-Date comparison is prevent an output

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script that I can run once every two weeks to clear out folders and files that haven't been accessed in two weeks or longer. I've written most of the script, and it works well until I add the following line of code:

```
Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime –lt $RefDate } |
```

For some reason, this code prevents `$condition` from having an output [see code below].

I use `$condition` later in a do-while to recursively delete folders, but it won't loop due to this, or export the data to a CSV folder anymore. [Removing this line lets it work again]

Here's the key sections that the line is used in/relevant to it:

```
$dPath = "C:\Users\my.name\Desktop\PowTest2\*\"

$RefDate = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1);

$condition = Get-ChildItem $dPath -recurse -force | 
                Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime –lt $RefDate } |
                Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | 
                Where-Object{$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0} | 
                select FullName 

write-output $RefDate;
write-output $condition
```

Above, `$RefDate` outputs as expected, `$condition` outputs nothing unless I remove the problematic line of code.

Edit:
Hi all,

Olaf made a good point, and asked me to check if the property is tracked for the folder. It appears it isn't, which would explain my issue. I'll update after more research and testing.

Comment: That just means all the folders in `$dPath` have been accessed at some point within the last hour

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. Yes, I'm using the `$RefDate` variable to delete all files/folders not accessed before that date. The issues is that line of code stop all outputs for the `$condition` variable. I have no idea why, it doesn't seem like it should have any affect like that

Comment: Hey Olaf, I'm using it for both, files don't require the loop so `$conditions` ouput doesn't matter for files. I know it's bulky, I'll cut it back why I've finished. I'm new to powershell as a language so I'm keeping the longer way for now :)

Comment: Yep, the hour is for testing purposes only!

Comment: That line checks if the folder is empty, as I can't delete any folders that have files in them :)

Comment: No, I didn't know that!

Comment: Ah no. Sorry. It's only the case with Get-Item (parent) in combination with Get-ChildItem. e.g. `(Get-Item C:\temp).LastAccessTime ; $t=Get-childitem C:\temp -Recurse -Directory ; (Get-item C:\temp).LastAccessTime` shows different times. Using only Get-ChildItem for child items doesn't affect the time.

Comment: Hey pwnosh, thank you for coming back to clarify. Unfortunately, I'm having no luck with using the accessdate property on the folders, so I'll likely just delete all empty folders, and track them via the export-csv and skip the issue altogether :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its been answered, but i was doing some reasearch and found a 7 month old post where it was answered, i changed it around to match what youd like "It deletes all files older than 13 days, so not sure if that works lol". Let me know if this help

OG POST: [Powershell delete folder files based on date range criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025203/powershell-delete-folder-files-based-on-date-range-criteria)

```
$path = "C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop\test"

foreach($file in (GEt-childitem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime 
-lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-14))} ))
{
if (($file.lastwritetime.Date.Day  -in 1,15,30 ) -or ($file -like '*weekly*'))
{continue}

  Remove-Item -Path $file.FullName}
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up settling for a script that deletes all of the files that haven't been removed after two weeks, and clears all empty folders. 

I got around the possibility of deleting a needed empty fold by just recording the folders that are removed. I'll give this a try though!